# Challenges Resurrecting an Old Flutter Project: Android Folder and Gradle

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I downloaded a Flutter project from 4 years ago, and I want to work on top of it. I already have an old version of the Flutter SDK, so I don't have problems with the dependencies. But for some reason, I can't run the app because of a problem in my Android folder. The error message is long, really long, but it looks like this:"

Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\pochoclo\youtube-search-flutter-bloc-master\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1
> ...
> ...
> ...

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Command: C:\Users\pochoclo\youtube-search-flutter-bloc-master\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

I don't know what to do; help is higly appreciated :)

Comment: I went through the process myself. Aizan's answer (using `fvm`) is a good short term strategy to get it running, but if your app relies on other services like Firebase (third party APIs), you will hit a lot of road blocks, because they kinda force you to update. Flutter's version management makes it hard to raise the SDK without breaking things, as you need to upgrade dependencies as well, and vice-versa. Essentially, you would find yourself regenerating the native project of your app and slowly solving all the issues in Dart to make it compatible with the new SDK. Fun times.

Answer (score 0):

JCenter shut down in 2021: https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown.

Try replacing `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()` wherever it occurs.

Comment: thanks! sadly this only resolves one of a hundread problems in the build. I guess I'll have to migrate the project, reconstructing from 0

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions.

**1. Downgrade your sdk**

You can downgrade your sdk to run the project. For that, you can use

```
flutter downgrade <version>
```

you can also use `FVM` if you don't want to change your current sdk, you can use FVM to download another sdk. You can read more [here](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/overview).

**2. Migrate your project**

It's a bit challenging as there will be many breaking changes but you can do it step by step. See flutter [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/upgrade) and you can also check [it](https://auberginesolutions.com/blog/upgrade-the-flutter-version/)

Comment: I currently have Flutter v1.0.0, so downgrading isn't an option. I suppose that manually migrating is the only solution

Comment: If you're comfortable migrating the project, you can check the resources I share. This will help you a lot

Comment: If any answer help you, you can accept and vote for it, it will help other users. @Agustin